# Execute method with arguments through action mapping in struts 2

Tags: struts2, argument-passing

How would I execute a method with an argument in my model based on the URL? Ie, `http://server/MyAction_Arg.action` maps to MyClass.MyMethod(Arg)? I tried this:

```
    <action name="MyAction_*" method="MyMethod({1})" class="example.MyClass">
        <result>page.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

but I get java.lang.NoSuchMethodException at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In struts2 you can accomplish this like this:

```
  server/myaction.action?arg=value
```

And in the MyClass action class you can declare a variable variable named arg with getter and setter. In the MyMethod() method you have access to the value of arg via the getArg() method.

Comment: No. You can include a form with a hidden field. But it is the most common way of sending data to an action.